# How to generate an array of float number with 2 decimal place

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I want to have an array of float number like this:
{0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.50, 1.75, 2.0, 2.25,..100}

How do i generate it until a 100 with code?

Comment: Which language? `iOS` is an operating system, not a code language. Also, the array you posted as an example is an antithesis of "random". Do you want a random array, or an array with a 0.25 step?

Comment: What language? Have you made any attempt? Post the code you have to do this and explain what issues you are having.

Comment: @Amadan: Objective-C language Please!. Not random 0.25 step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Objective-C (iOS):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

for (float i = 0.25; i <= 100; i = i + 0.25)
     [array addObject:@(i)];
```

Comment: You can't add `float` to an `NSArray`. You need to wrap the `float` in an `NSNumber`.